# Show contents of a cell if two other cells in the same row match

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a calendar view within Google Sheets using `=CountIfs` to match installer name to installation date and return a value of **0** or **1**.

Below that I want to add in the postcode of the job it has counted (if it has one).

I am trying to match the same as above, but then present a 3rd cell (postcode).

Here is the count formula:

```
=countifs(Jobs!$S:$S,$A7,Jobs!$T:$T,C$6)
```

So effectively, I want to match:

> Column S on Jobs tab to field A7
> Column T on Jobs tab to field C6

Then if there is a match return the contents of Column M of the same row.

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of a spreadsheet to show exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: Looks like a typical `VLookup()` example.